# Bloquear orientación pantalla móvil en phonegap

Tags: html5, cordova, phonegap

He realizado un juego para móvil con phonegap/cordova el cual me interesa que este siempre en la orientación portrait ya que de ese modo la pantalla esta perfecta para poder jugar.

He buscado y probado diversas maneras y ninguna me funciona no se si es por el dispositivo, es un samsung con android 5.1 o es que no lo implemento bien.

He probado ubicando en el archivo config.xml la instrucción:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

También con el plugin cordova-plugin-screen-orientation con la instrucción

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

Ninguna me funciona bien. Sigue pudiendo cambiar la orientación.

Answer (score 0):

Eso puede ser un tema de la disposición de tus archivos, el archivo config.xml y el index.html tienen que estar en el mismo directorio en la raiz del archivo zip que subiste a PhoneGap build.

*(Los hooks que metas no deberían estar incluidos en el archivo zip)*

Prueba con la orientación de paisaje (apaisada horizontal de toda la vida)

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

para confirmar que los tienes en el mismo directorio y te funciona.

Comment: Fallo mío, no funciona en el emulador phonegap, una vez lo pasas al móvil la instrucción preference funciona perfectamente. De todas formas yo no tengo los archivos en el mismo directorio y me funciona igual, tengo el config.xml en la raíz y el index.html debajo del directorio www